# Using awk to grab only numbers from a string

Tags: regex, awk

Background:
I have a column that *should* get user input in form of "Description text ref12345678". I have existing scripts that grab the reference number but unfortunately some users add it incorrectly so instead of `"ref12345678"` it can be `"ref 12345678"`, `"RF12345678"`, `"abcd12345678"` or any variation. Naturally the wrong formatting breaks some of the triggered scripts. 
For now I can't control the user input to this field, so I want to make the scripts later in the pipeline just to get the number.

At the moment I'm stripping the letters with `awk '{gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/, "")}; 1'`, but substitution seems like an inefficient solution. (I know I can do this also with `sed -n 's/.*[a-zA-Z]//p'` and `tr -d '[[:alpha:]]'` but they are essentially the same and I want awk for additional programmability).

The question is, is there a way to set awk to either print only numbers from a string, or set delimits to numeric items in a string? (or is substitution really the most efficient solution for this problem).

So in summary: how do I use awk for `$ echo "ref12345678"` to print only "12345678" without substitution?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

if awk is **not** a must:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\+'
```

example:

```
kent$ echo "ref12345678"|grep -o '[0-9]\+'
12345678
```

with **awk** for your example:

```
kent$ echo "ref12345678"|awk -F'[^0-9]*' '$0=$2'     
12345678
```

Comment: Thanks, the provided awk example didn't completely do it, but led me to the correct path:`$ echo "ref12345678"| awk -F'[^0-9]*' '{print $2}'` does the trick on awk that ships with OS X.

Answer (score 16):

You can also try the following with awk assuming there will be only one number in a string:

```
awk '{print ($0+0)}'
```

This converts your entire string to numeric, and the way that awk is implemented only the values that fit the numeric description will be left. Thus for example:

```
echo "19 trees"|awk '{print ($0+0)}'
```

will produce:
19

Comment: Although this works only when the number is in front

Answer (score 4):

In AWK you can specify **multiple conditions** like:

---

```
($3~/[[:digit:]+]/ && $3 !~/[[:alpha:]]/ && $3 !~/[[:punct:]]/ ) {print $3}
```

---

will display only digit without any alphabet and punctuation.
with ***!~*** means ***not contain any***.

Answer (score 3):

grep works perfectly :

```
$ echo "../Tin=300_maxl=9_rdx=1.1" | grep -Eo '[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?'
300
9
1.1
```

Step by step explanation:

```
-E
```

Use extended regex.

```
-o
```

Return only the matches, not the context

```
[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?+
```

Match numbers which are identified as:

```
[+-]?
```

An optional leading sign

```
[0-9]+
```

One or more numbers

```
([.][0-9]+)?
```

An optional period followed by one or more numbers.

it is convenient to put the output in an array

```
arr=($(echo "../Tin=300_maxl=9_rdx=1.1" | grep -Eo '[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?'))
```

and then use it like this

```
Tin=${arr[0]}
maxl=${arr[1]}
etc..
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option (assuming `GNU awk`) involves specifying a non-numeric regular expression as a separator

```
awk -F '[^0-9]+' '{OFS=" "; for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i != "") print($i)}'
```