# Get the first element of a line and another one after a specific word at the same time

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

Basically I have a file with this format :

```
12:23:36 some text here length 256 some text here
12:24:37 some text here length 23 some text here
```

As the quantity of words vary, I wouldlike to only get the timestamp and the length value with a shell command.
I know how to do them separately (respectively with awk and grep) but I can't find a proper way to get both.

EDIT : 
Here is the structure of my lines, the IPs have been modified (I get this from Tcpdump):

```
06:30:51.498909 IP 2.2.2.2 > 1.1.1.1: Flags [.], ack 2326465, win 65535, length 0

06:30:51.609162 IP 3.3.3.3 > 4.4.4.4: Flags [.], ack 1654645, win 65535, length 0
```

The length isn't always the last number though and there can be more text in some parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^(..:..:..).*length.*([0-9]+).*/\1 \2/' file
```

- `-E` - use extended regular expression
- `^(..:..:..)` captures the timestamp
- `([0-9]+)` matches the length
- `\1 \2` replaces the entire line with matched parts

For your file, it gives this output:

```
12:23:36 256
12:24:37 23
```

Comment: See my edits, I ran your code on this but it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: You should change to `sed -E 's/^(..:..:..).*length ([0-9]+).*/\1 \2/' file` (no spaces around the first `.*`).

Answer (score 1):

If your text doesn't include numbers, you can use `sed` and remove all `[a-zA-Z]` characters:

```
sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g' file
```

---

```
$ cat test
12:23:36 some text here length 256 some text here
12:24:37 some text here length 23 some text here
$ sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g' test
12:23:36     256
12:24:37     23
```

Another solution would be using `awk` to print the first column, and a regex to extract the digits part, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16618516/1735406). I'm not `awk` expert, but should be something like:

```
gawk -F' [^0-9]* ' 'BEGIN { ORS=" " };{print $1} {print $0=$2"\n"}' file
```

Comment: I have some digits unfortunately. How could I combine both the instructions in a single line as you mention ?

Comment: @Tiffany Change the regex depending on your pattern, or if there's no pattern, you should consider another approach.

Comment: This solution works well as long as there is a single number other than the timestamp.  If there are more than one number, it will match all of them.

Comment: @codeforester what numbers you want to extract? After the ack?

Comment: After length please !

Comment: @Tiffany `sed -E 's/^(..:..:..).*length.*([0-9]+).*/\1 \2/' test` should work.

Comment: Don't know what I did wrong when first trying but it works like a charm now... Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: @Tiffany Note that it's not the same as posted in codeforester's answer, it's modified a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If the timestamp is always at the start of line,

You can try this sed

```
sed -E 's/([^. ]*).*length ([^ ]*).*/\1 \2/' infile
```